# Workfront API - List of tasks modified after a specific datetime

Tags: workfront-api

Is it possible to get the list of tasks modified after a specific date time using the search API ? 
Specifically, we are looking for all the auditnotes added after any specific time.

Answer (score 0):

The auditNote is not a separate object so it won't have its own timestamp. You can search for the last update being after date D with a search on `task?lastUpdateDate=D&lastUpdateDate_Mod=ge` but it will look for any update perofrmed on the task, not just an auditnote update.

You could always search for all tasks modified after a given date (as above) and then iterate through the returned task IDs, each time searching for all notes whose objectID is the task's ID and filtering again for dates >= your audit date. You could also filter based on the audittype as listed below.

```
ST (Status Change)
AA (Attachment Action)
SC (Scope Change)
NO (Note)
GE (General Edit)
CM (Combined Entry)
ER (Error Entry
```

Comment: Here is the example of the API call /attask/api/v6.0/task/search?projectID=5819d0160009c41c7ad951208f3aa398&apiKey=XYZ&lastUpdateDate_Mod=gte&lastUpdateDate=2017-04-27
However, auditNote change is not tracked under lastUpdateDate.

Comment: That does make things trickier. Can you still search for all notes for a task that does have an auditnote and see if it shows up as a note object? If so, the 2nd half of my answer should help and you can just iterate through all tasks in your system and look for notes entered after the specified date.

Comment: That is not working either. For testing, a updatestatus is added to a task. That task is not being returned by the API.